# Template engine for CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp, smarty, laravel

I want to use **Smarty** or **Blade** (Laravel) template engine in CakePHP 2.3.
It's possible?

If yes, how?

If you know other template engines for CakePHP, tell me.

Comment: Before I was aggressively against any template systems in php. Now that I've worked on some js apps that utilize template/binding engines I find plain php templates tedious to write and hard to read. Despite having very bad experiences with smarty, I decided to give it a try and it didn't work out. I can't say it's bad in general but you just can't get any advanced stuff done with it. The CakePHP plugin is basically undocumented and incomplete, so be prepared. I wouldn't go as far to call template engines useless overhead, but you should definitely weigh the pros and cons yourself.

Comment: IMHO the only valid reason for using a template engine is when you want to avoid direct php input from foreign people but have to give them some programming like functionality. But even in this case, most of the time something like wordpress short tags work a lot better and are easy to parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you'll have to wrap the vendor lib [in a view class extending the base view class of CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#creating-your-own-view-classes).

But template engines are an useless overhead and it does not matter much if the designer has to learn something like {Foo.field} vs echo $foo['field'];.

Just google for "cakephp smarty" and "cakephp twig view" and you'll find something. And if you really want that overhead, even if it is cached, I would go for twig over Smarty.

A modern, OOP based view solution for CakePHP is https://github.com/jameswatts/cake-toolkit, you can build your custom objects, inherit them as needed, overwrite them... the usual OOP stuff. And it could be even combined with a template engine.

Comment: There is something about how the source code looks: eg. its more like {Foo.field} vs <?php echo $foo['field']; ?>

Comment: Best comment : But template engines are an useless overhead and it does not matter much if the designer has to learn something like {Foo.field} vs echo $foo['field'];.

Answer (score 1):

this may help u http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/tclineks/2006/10/27/how-to-use-smarty-with-cake-smartyview

but for The decision to use Smarty over traditional native PHP templating should not be taken lightly. Although
Smarty is clearly a great tool for simple templating, its functionality is still only a subset of what might
be needed in large - scale projects.
Although it can be extended with native PHP through the use of the {php } and {/php } tags, doing so
rather defeats the purpose of using safe templates in the first place. Indeed, Smarty ’ s own Web site states
that “ embedding PHP code into templates is highly discouraged. ”
The skills and experience of any other developers working with you on the project are likely to be the
deciding factor. If you are the sole engineer working on a project, it is almost certainly better to use
native templating. Conversely, if the project requires a number of designers and HTML specialists
working on the output from your scripts, Smarty templates are a much safer bet, because they allow
such individuals to manipulate the display logic of your application to their hearts ’ content, without
touching the PHP code behind it.